# Getting the xml soap response instead of raw data

Tags: python, request, elementtree

I am trying to get the soap response and read few tags and then put the key and values inside a dictionary.

Better would be if I could use the response generated directly and preform regd operations to it.
But since I was not able to do that, I tried storing the response in an xml file and then using that for operations.

My problem is that the response generated is in a raw form. How to resolve this.

```
Example: &lt;medical:totEeCnt val=&quot;2&quot; /&gt;&#xd;
          &lt;medical:totMbrCnt val=&quot;2&quot; /&gt;&#xd;
          &lt;medical:totDepCnt val=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&#xd;


def soapTest():
    request = """<soapenv:Envelope.......
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth('', '')
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml', 'SOAPAction': "", 'Host': 'bfx-b2b....com'}
        url = "https://bfx-b2b....com/B2BWEB/services/IProductPort"
        response = requests.post(url, data=request, headers=headers, auth=auth, verify=True)

        # Open local file
        fd = os.open('planRates.xml', os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)

        # Convert response object into string
        response_str = str(response.content)

        # Write response to the file
        os.write(fd, response_str)

        # Close the file
        os.close(fd)

        tree = ET.parse('planRates.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        dict = {}

        print root
        for plan in root.findall('.//{http://services.b2b.../types/rates/dental}dentPln'):  # type: object

            plan_id = plan.get('cd')
            print plan

            print plan_id

            for rtGroup in plan.findall('.//{http://services.b2b....com/types/rates/dental}censRtGrp'):

                #print rtGroup
                for amt in rtGroup.findall('.//{http://services.b2b....com/types/rates/dental}totAnnPrem'):
                    # print amt
                    print amt.get('val')
                    amount =  amt.get('val')
                    dict[plan_id] = amount

                print dict
```

Update-:
I did few things, what I am not able to understand is that ,
using this, the operations further are working,

```
     tree = ET.parse('data/planRates.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        dict = {}
        print tree
        print root
for plan in root.findall(..
```

output -

```
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x100d7b910>
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x101500450>
```

But after using this ,it is not working

```
    tree = ET.fromstring(response.text)
    print tree
for plan in tree.findall(..
```

output-:

```
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x10d624910>
```

Basically I am using the same object only .

Comment: Assuming that `ET` is `lxml.etree`: why don't you `doc = ET.fromstring(response_str)`?

Comment: After adding this , what I can see written is just <Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x1047a9910>

Comment: Instead of writing to a file ,can I directly use the response with ET??

Comment: That's what i suggested: you can use the response.text to create an 'ObjectifiedElement' which represents the root element of your response. But while doing this you should be wary to strip the soapEnvelope from your response before doing the `ET.fromstring`.

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting. Could you help me with an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you get a response that you want as proper xml object:

```
rt = resp.text.encode('utf-8')

# printed rt is something like:
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://...">
 <soap:Envelope
 <AirShoppingRS xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST" Version="16.1">
 <Document>...</soap:Envelope</soap:Envelope>'

# striping soapEnv
startTag = '<AirShoppingRS '
endTag = '</AirShoppingRS>'
trimmed = rt[rt.find(startTag): rt.find(endTag) + len(endTag)]

# parsing
from lxml import etree as et
root = et.fromstring(trimmed)
```

With this root element you can use find method, xpath or whatever you prefer.
Obviously you need to change the start and endtags to extract the correct element from the response but you get the idea, right?

Comment: When I am printing the trimmed part , I am getting  something like below-`&lt;uesb2b:information&gt;&#xd;
    &lt;uesb2b:srvcErrOccur&gt;&#xd;
      &lt;uesb2b:rtnCd&gt;INF0020&lt;/uesb2b:rtnCd&gt;&#xd;` I am guessing due to this nothing is working for me

Comment: Looks like the < and > are escaped ... you might be able to replace that: '&lt;' should be replaced with '<'; '&gt;'with '>' and '&amp;' with '&'. To learn more about this you can look up info for HTML string escaping.